Select from DataFrame based on column order of other DataFrame
import pandas as pd

df_a = pd.DataFrame({'Number':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
                     'Column_A': ['C','E','G','L','E','N','P','R'],
                     'Column_B': ['D','F','H','M','Z','O','Q','S']})

df_b = pd.DataFrame({'Number':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
                     'Column_C': ['A','E','L','H','C','Q'],
                     'Column_D': ['B','F','M','G','F','P']})

mask = (((df_a['Column_A'].isin(df_b['Column_C'])) & (df_a['Column_B'].isin(df_b['Column_D']))) | ((df_a['Column_A'].isin(df_b['Column_D'])) & (df_a['Column_B'].isin(df_b['Column_C']))))

df_a[mask]

df_a
   Number Column_A Column_B
0       1        C        D
1       2        E        F
2       3        G        H
3       4        L        M
4       5        E        Z
5       6        N        O
6       7        P        Q
7       8        R        S

df_b
   Number Column_C Column_D
0       1        A        B
1       2        E        F
2       3        L        M
3       4        H        G
4       5        C        F
5       6        Q        P

df_a[mask]
   Number Column_A Column_B
1       2        E        F
2       3        G        H
3       4        L        M
6       7        P        Q


Find the pair of Column_C and Column_D of df_b in Column_A and Column_B of df_a
Column_C could be Column_B while Column_D is Column_A (AND-Condition)

Assuming there are more columns to "mask", the condition will become very long.
Is there a better solution with merge/join or anything?

You can aggregate the selected columns as set (per row) and use the same logic:
mask = (df_a[['Column_A', 'Column_B']].agg(set, axis=1)
        .isin(df_b[['Column_C', 'Column_D']].agg(set, axis=1))
       )

out = df_a[mask]

Output:
   Number Column_A Column_B
1       2        E        F
2       3        G        H
3       4        L        M
6       7        P        Q

Intermediates:
df_a[['Column_A', 'Column_B']].agg(set, axis=1)

0    {C, D}
1    {E, F}
2    {G, H}
3    {M, L}
4    {Z, E}
5    {N, O}
6    {P, Q}
7    {R, S}
dtype: object


df_b[['Column_C', 'Column_D']].agg(set, axis=1)

0    {B, A}
1    {E, F}
2    {M, L}
3    {G, H}
4    {C, F}
5    {P, Q}
dtype: object

